# Архитектура стека TCP/IP (уровни, назначение, потоки данных, примеры

Tags: ip, tcp

Добрый день.

Не могли бы вы подсказать в чём заключается архитектура стека TCP/IP (уровни, назначение, потоки данных, примерып ротоколов), адресная информация в TCP/IP. IP адреса, IP-сети, порты TCP\UDP.

Comment: подсказать ... хм ... по вышеперечисленным вопросам ответ потянет на небольшую книжку, страничек на 100

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать какую нибудь хорошую книгу по данным темам?

Comment: начните читать с такой [UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2881910/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напоминает студенческий билет по предмету "Компьютерные сети". 
Есть как минимум два хороших источника по теме, это:

- Танненбаум, Компьютерные сети
- Снейдер, Эффективное программирование TCP/IP

Comment: Добавил бы к этому списку еще "Компьютерные сети. Принципы, технологии, протоколы." Олифер